# Addition of Vectors.

Tags: vectors

**Q.** If vectors **A=i+2j+4k** and **B=5i** represent the two sides of a triangle, then the third side of the triangle can have length equal to:

a) 6

b)$\sqrt{56}$

c)both (a) and (b)

d)none of the above

Following directly into the answer: **A+B=6i+2j+4k** then the magnitude of **A+B** (which is the line that makes will be $\sqrt{56}$ and hence option 'b'. But my text marks the answer as 'c'.

But how can this happen if both **A** and **B** are specific vectors and has only one magnitude and a single direction can have two different resultants? Am I wrong somewhere, or is it my textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two answers because you can form two essentially different triangles: one triangle by matching the tip of one vector to the tail of the second and another triangle by matching the tails of the two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes c) is also correct take the cross product of $A$ with $B$ and equate it to $A×C$ and $B×C$ hence $C$ will come $4i -2j -4k$ because the area of the triangle is constant
Hence $C=6$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please edit your post and clarify your explanation and type the equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).